# Github workflow - how to make the site live

Tags: git, live, web-hosting

Say I've been working and collaborating on my project, doing all the changes locally, then pushing to a remote repo on github so I can collab with others.

I've not been able to find much discussion about what actually happens when you're ready to make your project accessible to the public. (i.e. for the end user)

Is it just a case of fetching the master branch to your computer then uploading the files via FTP to your web host? Or do I need to get my webhost to install git on my server then I can do a git push directly? It seems strange that a lot of the major web hosts, don't mention anything about git in their online docs.

Comment: This is entirely dependent on your web hosting provider. If it has no git support, you should use appropriate scripts for the upload. As to making it public, it is up to you: for instance you can tag your versions.

Comment: @fge is right, it depends on your hosting provider, and also the hosting solution you have - if you have a shared server, you may not be able to install GIT, but if it's dedicated or virtual, you may be able to and then it's down to how you intend to make releases. It can be as simple as FTPing, or you can do a Git pull to update your codebase, or as FGE suggested, tag your code and do releases of those. The web host wouldn't normally take care of this for you because it differs from project to project.

Comment: If you are lucky and you have `git` in your hosting, you can take a look at [Capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano) to follow a good workflow when deploying

Comment: As commented above, it depends on hosting provider.
I'll try to explain the basics with aws ec2 configuration, 

create a instance and setup the environment required for deploying the application, though in case of many web hosting providers it comes configured.
Install git and add the id_rsa.pub key to your git.
ssh to the ec2 instance using the key, do a git clone and point your document root in server configuration to you application.

Answer (score 0):

Having Git on server would be the best. Though, if you have not access to those levels, just push a particular revision with https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp.

Whether using OSX, you can consider this GUI-based pretty convenient workflow (I also use for some WordPress stuff): http://eppz.eu/blog/push-git-to-ftp/